# Resolve the struct passed to a function in Runtime

Tags: reflection, struct, go

I have the below interface that implements a simpler Active Record Like implementation for my persistent layer.

```
type DBInterface interface {
  FindAll(collection []byte) map[string]string
  FindOne(collection []byte, id int) map[string]string
  Destroy(collection []byte, id int) bool
  Update(collection []byte, obj map[string]string ) map[string]string
  Create(collection []byte, obj map[string]string) map[string]string
}
```

The application has different collection's that it talks to and different corresponding models. I need to be able to pass in a dynamic Struct , instead of a map for the value obj ( ie. Update , Create Signatures )

I can't seem to understand how to use reflection to resolve the Struct , any guidance would help.

More details on what I am trying explain :

Consider the below snippet from mgo example from https://labix.org/mgo

```
    err = c.Insert(&Person{"Ale", "+55 53 8116 9639"},
               &Person{"Cla", "+55 53 8402 8510"})
```

When we insert data to the collection , we do a &Person I want to be able to pass in this bit &Person{"Ale", "+55 53 8116 9639"} but the method receiving the would only know it in the Run time. Because it could be a Person , Car , Book etc Struct depending on the func calling the method

Comment: I don't understand what your mean by `use reflection to resolve the Struct`; can you show what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @JimB Added a trivial example on what I am trying to achieve

Comment: If you just want to pass it into mgo, you don't need to do the reflection, just give the interface to `c.Insert`. Do you need to operate on these structs yourself too?

Comment: Well , I just wanted to have a interface between my persistent layer and the Repositories so that I can change the persistent layer by re-implementing the Interface to support a different Persistent layer without having to change a lot of my other code. Ideally I would have to operate on the structs as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare your obj type as interface{}

   ```
        Update(collection []byte, obj interface{} ) map[string]string
   ```
2. Now you can pass Person,Book,Car etc to this function as obj.
3. Use a type switch inside Update function for each actual struct

   ```
       switch t := obj.(type){
       case Car://Handle Car type
       case Perosn:
       case Book:
                     }
   ```

   Structs needs to be decided at compile time.No dynamic types in Go.Even interfaces are static types.